How to access existing code in Salesforce
I am an admin but not familiar with apex coding. How do I access existing code? Is it through Developer Console?
As I am looking through the related questions, I came across Visual Studio Code questions. Is it what I should be using?

Going through the Developer Console is one way to see/edit the existing code in your org, but probably not the preferred method.
Using the Salesforce CLI (a.k.a. Salesforce DX, sfdx) is the current, officially supported way to deal with code and code-adjacent things. After getting it set up, it'd be something like sf project retrieve start -m ApexClass
Using ANT with the ANT Migration Tool (alongside an official plugin for Oracle's Eclipse IDE) was the previous solution (there was a period of time when Atom/SublimeText with Mavensmate, an unofficial plugin, was in vogue).
VSCode is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) which alongside the Salesforce CLI and some official plugins is what you would generally use to create/edit code. You could use the "Org Browser" in VSCode, but as a general rule, the Salsforce CLI is what you'd want to use for getting at the code.
I suppose that for completeness, there is also the Metadata API, but that's not something that most people use directly. Using the Metadata API would be like growing wheat, reaping, threshing, winnowing, and milling it into flour to make bread as opposed to just buying a bag a flour to make bread.

Maybe worth mentioning that Lightning Web Components (which are likely to contain significant portions of the UI code in a modern org) can't be viewed via the Developer Console - and neither in Salesforce's Setup area, which remains an important place to view source code too. For completeness ;-) one could finally mention version control in this context, hoping that something like a Github repository represents the single source of truth.
